# defaultdict vs dict element initialization

Tags: python, dictionary, defaultdict

I am trying to optimize the performance of a script that looks up similar words in a lexicon for each word given.

Each unique word is to be split into letter n-grams and for each n-gram, the lexicon returns a list of words that contain the same letter n-gram. Each word from this list is then added to a dictionary as a key and it's value is incremented by one. This gives me a dictionary of similar words with corresponding frequency scores.

```
word_dict = {}
get = word_dict.get
for letter_n_gram in word:
    for entry in lexicon[n_gram]:
        word_dict[entry] = get(entry, 0) + 1
```

This implementation works, but the script could supposedly run faster by switching the `dict` for `collections.defaultdict`.

```
word_dd = defaultdict(int)
for letter_n_gram in word:
    for entry in lexicon[n_gram]:
        word_dd[entry] += 1
```

No other code has been changed.

I was under the impression that both code snippets (most importantly the score adding) should work in the exact same way, i.e. if the key exists, increase its value by 1, if it does not exist, create the key and set the value to 1.

After running the new code, however, some of the keys had values of 0, which I find logically impossible.

Is my logic or knowledge of `defaultdict` functionality flawed? If not, how can any value in `word_dd` be set to 0?

edit: I am also very sure that no other part of the script skews these results, as I test the dictionary immediately after shown code by using:

```
for item in word_dd.iteritems():
    if item[1] == 0:
        print "Found zero value element"
        break
```

Comment: What keys had 0 value? Are you sure those keys are in the dictionary already?

Comment: How do you test for the values? *Any* key access will create the key; so `word_dd['nonesuch']` doesn't assign, but *will* create the value for you.

Comment: Testing for values added in the question

Comment: Your understanding of `defaultdict` seems to be fine: it should be impossible for the code you've posted to end up with `0 in word_dd.values()` being True. Are you sure you don't have any code involving `word_dd` between the two pieces of code you've posted? Also, defaultdict will only run noticeably faster than dict.get/dict.setdefault when the default is expensive to compute - which constant ints definitely aren't. The reason to consider it here is because it makes your code *simpler*, not faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alas, I have found the fault in my code.

As there are many consequent word n-grams with the same tested word in my input set, I am only creating the dictionary of similar words once per unique tested word.

This dictionary is then used for other purposes with keys being tested multiple times. This, of course, can create zero-valued elements, if the dictionary is `collections.defaultdict` and the default factory is not set to `None`.

Testing for the zero-valued elements was, however, done in each main loop - therefore finding zero-valued elements created in the previous loop.

After indenting the testing code into the proper part, the results are as expected - no zero-valued elements immediately after creation.

I would like to apologize to everyone for the faulty and incomplete construction of my question - it was impossible for anyone else to find the error.

Answer (score 6):

When you access a key in a `defaultdict`, if it is not there, it will be created automatically. Since we have `int` as the default factory function, it creates the key and gives the default value 0.

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(int)
print d["a"]
# 0
print d
# defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'a': 0})
```

So, before accessing the key, you should make sure that it exists in the `defaultdict` instance, like this

```
print "a" in d
# False
```

Comment: This is the whole point of the `defaultdict` optimization. It removes the overhead of `get(entry, 0)` in the other case.

Comment: Edited my question, please reiterate

Comment: @Deutherius If `1` was not already in the ddict, it will be created and default value 0 will be used. I explained this behaviour in the answer. Please check.

Comment: I was under the impression that `word_ddict.iteritems()` will return an iterator over existing items in the dictionary - the `item` in my testing loop is a tuple of (key, value), hence the `1`, which is an index, not a dictionary query.

Comment: @Deutherius Oh Sorry, I misunderstood that. Anyway, you are not checking the value, bu the key, right? They key can have zeros. Can you please show a sample of the actual data, to reproduce this problem?

Comment: @thefourtheye I believe I am checking the value, checking for the key would be done with index `0`. Also, due to the size of the lexicon, which usually returns thousands of entries for each letter n-gram, it would be rather impractical to post or manually go through the actual data being processed.

Comment: @Deutherius I was wrong again. Sorry about that. Can you please reproduce the problem with a sample dataset?

Answer (score 6):

*Any* item access to a key will materialise the value:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(int)
>>> d['foo']
0
```

Use containment to test for the existence instead:

```
>>> 'bar' in d
False
>>> 'foo' in d
True
```

Since you are counting n-grams, you probably want to look at [`collections.Counter()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) as well:

```
from collections import Counter

word_counter = Counter()
for letter_n_gram in word:
    word_counter.update(lexicon[n_gram])
```

where the `Counter.update()` will update counts for all entries the `lexicon[n_gram]` expression returns.

Like `defaultdict(int)`, `Counter()` objects materialise values automatically, defaulting to integer `0`.

Comment: As per my [latest answer to thefourtheye](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23044093/defaultdict-vs-dict-element-initialization#comment35208659_23044152), I don't think I am testing for the presence of zero value wrongly. `word_dd.iteritems()` shouldn't, AFAIK, create any elements.
I will definitely check out `collections.Counter`, thank you.

Comment: @Deutherius: no, `.iteritems()` won't. The code you posted in your question won't either though.

Comment: @Deutherius: the **only** way you can have `0` values in your dictionary is either accessing the key (so `dictionary[key]` anywhere the key isn't defined in the dictionary yet), or by directly assigning `0` (through assignment, augmented assignment or `.update()`).